# Sign PDF in TCPDF using cert from AATL

Tags: php, linux, tcpdf, signing

We wan't to sign our PDF documents using TCPDF. This does work so far using `setSignature()` and a self-signed certificate. For the purpose of full validation in Acrobat Reader, we want to use a certificate of a CA that is contained in Adobe AATL (for example see certificate from [Sectigo](https://sectigo.com/ssl-certificates-tls/document-signing-certificates)). But these certificates are issued on USB hardware tokens only.

The signing is done on a headless webserver running PHP on Debian 11. What options do we have to get this up and running?Can the certificate and private key be extracted from such USB devices? Or is there any chance to talk to the USB device on-the-fly via PHP?

There don't seems to be any guides for this use case. Using a cloud service for signing is not an option.

Comment: I will have to do the same thing in a few months, and didn't realize the certs are delivered on an encrypted USB device until I read this post.  I will post what I find out when I work on this.

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? We need to do the same thing.

Comment: @dearsina We haven't started implementation yet, because it's not that cheap. The plan is: 1) Buy certificate from CA that is able to issue certs for Google Cloud KMS (for example from ensured.com) and 2) use SetaPDF-Signer for signing PDFs in PHP.